# How can my discord bot filter who can send me a DM?

Tags: discord, discord.js

Is this possible with the discord.js API to enable my custom bot to filter all direct messages and reject some from members that doesn't have a specific role even if they are in my friend list or in the same guilds ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want the bot to block certain users from sending you DMs?

If so, then it's not possible.
Bots do not have access to your DMs with other people, nor are they able to emit an event when someone DMs you.

The discord API does not provide such functionality and it will probably never do.